# Calling ASP.NET Web API in jQuery from an Area

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC project with an Area named MyArea. A View in there, Index, contains this javascript at the bottom (triggered during onclick of button):

```
<script>
    function x() {
        var url = WebApi.Url() + "orders";
        url = "http://localhost:43292/api/employees";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

the Web API is like this:

```
[Route("api/employees")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
{
    List<Employee> employees = null;

    //... get employees

    return employees;
}
```

but it is always returning "Resource not found". 
I think it is a problem when it is inside an Area, as when I move the same script inside a View that is not in an Area, the Web API gets called succesfully.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.

Oh, and I am using MVC 5 if that helps.

## EDIT

Looks like it works when I tried a bare bones project just as SBirthare said. And I think the problem lies when I alter the Area route config. As I want that Area to be the default page, I've remove the leading Area name in its route config. So from:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Employee_default",
    "Employee/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

to

```
// No leading Employee
context.MapRoute(
    "Employee_default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Removing the leading Area name results in "Resource not found (404)" when calling Web API.

So my question would be what can I do in this situation to make this work?

Comment: What's generated url?

Comment: check in the console the request path

Comment: I tried your code with a new Web API project, changed index.cshtml into area as well as outside. It just works. Are you sure about the URL being set correctly? Make sure the url address you are using in your view is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I'll try on a clean project and see how it goes, without altering anything and post here of the result.

Comment: Please see edit above.